# What's the point of adding liquidity minimum wtih negative ticks

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, uniswap

Why would someone call mint() and burn() liquidity on uniswap v3 with negative lower and/or upper ticks? I saw a few people who did this while exploring some datasets.

Answer (score 3):

Negative tick means prices less than 1; positive ticks prices more than 1, and tick value of 0 means price exactly equal to 1.

The Uniswap v3 [whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf) has an equation (Eq. 6.1) that defines the relation between tick `i` and price at that tick `p(i)`:

() = 1.0001 ^

In Uniswap, the price is defined as the relation between `x` and `y` (the virtual amounts of tokens in the pool): `P = y/x`. If there are more `x` than `y` in the pool, then the price less than 1.0. From the equation 6.1, `i`-th power of 1.0001 is less than 1.0 only if `i` is negative.